# send email with Restricted Gmail SMTP server

Tags: c#, email

i am trying to send a email with google's [Restricted Gmail SMTP server](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)

this is my code:

```
try
{
    var mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("from@email.com");
    mail.To.Add("myemail@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "subject";
    mail.Body= "body";

    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("aspmx.l.google.com");
    SmtpServer.Port = 25;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
this is the output of my catch:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Error sending e-mail. ---> System .net. WebException: Cannot connect to the remote server--->
```

Help please

Comment: Can you connect normally from where you run this code to port 25 on aspmx.l.google.com ?

Comment: I do not know, how can i test it? if i ping aspmx.l.google.com i get repley.

Comment: telnet/putty to that server on that port.

Comment: no i can not connect to it

Comment: Then you have a firewall in the way...

Comment: If I turn off my fire wall I still can't connect with Telnet, i try: "telnet aspmx.l.google.com 25" and get "Connection is made to ASPMX. L. Google. com... cannot connect to the host, on port 25: Connection creation failed"

Comment: Its not necessarily your machine. It can be one of a number on the network you are on.. only you can determine where and what is in the way

Comment: ok thanks, but if i use this in a application other machine's go block it too?

Comment: it will depend on the other machine - you cant guarantee ports are open anywhere... Example: most companies block you from using port 25 to outside direct..

Comment: Many ISPs (as well as companies) block port 25 so they don't end up on spam blacklists. You're not sending spam, but many have tried using techniques like yours.  The best way to handle this kind of outbound email is to take a look at sendgrid or one of the other transactional email service providers. Some of them have reasonable free service tiers.